# How to drag and drop nodes using JQuery jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have the following code to create a treeview but is it possible to make each node drag and droppable?  I've attached a screen shot of how it looks currently.  I want to allow the user to re-arrange the order of the nodes in the tree.

Many thanks,

**How it looks**

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXvv8.png)

**JS Code snippet**

```
    $(function () {
        "use strict";

        $("#grid").jqGrid({
            url: "stub.json",
            datatype: "json",
            colNames: [ 'id', 'Prestations'],
            colModel: [
                {name: 'id', width: 100, key: true, hidden: true},
                {name: 'name', width: 785, sortable: false}
            ],
            sortname: 'id',
            sortorder: "asc",
            hiddengrid: true,
            gridview: true,
            treeGrid: true,
            treeGridModel: "adjacency",
            ExpandColumn: 'name',
            ExpandColClick: true,
            jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, root: function (obj) { return obj; } },
            height: "auto"
        });
    });
```

**HTML code**

```
 <table class="table table-bordered tree-move">
    <tbody>
    <tr class="treegrid-1"><td>Tablets / Smartphones</td></tr>
        <tr class="treegrid-2 treegrid-parent-1"><td>Node 1-1</td></tr>
        <tr class="treegrid-3 treegrid-parent-1"><td>Node 1-2</td></tr>
            <tr class="treegrid-4 treegrid-parent-3"><td>Node 1-2-1</td></tr>
            <tr class="treegrid-5 treegrid-parent-3"><td>Node 1-2-2</td></tr>
        <tr class="treegrid-6 treegrid-parent-1"><td>Node 1-3</td></tr>
        <tr class="treegrid-7 treegrid-parent-1"><td>Node 1-4</td></tr>
    <tr class="treegrid-1"><td>Laptops</td></tr>
    <tr class="treegrid-1"><td>Desktops</td></tr>
    <tr class="treegrid-1"><td>Components</td></tr>
    <tr class="treegrid-1"><td>Emerging Technologies</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```